# conditional probability

Tags: probability

In a Blind tasting of wines from Bordeaux and Napa valley,a wine expert has 90% chance of correctly identifying that a wine is from Bordeaux and 80% chance of correctly identifying wine from Napa Valley.If 60% of wines at a tasting are from Napa,what is the probability that a random selected wine is from Napa Valley,given that the wine expert said it was from Napa?

N=event wine from a tasting is from Napa
B=even wine from a tasting is from Bordeaux 
C=correctly identify wine
$P(N|C)=\frac{P(N)*P(C|N)}{P(N)*p(C|N)+P(B)*p(C|B)}=  \frac{0.6*0.8}{0.6*0.8+0.4*0.9$}=0.57$

correct answer is 0.92

Comment: "C=correctly identifying the wine" is what threw you.  The condition is "given that the wine expert *said it was from Napa*" rather than that the expert was correct (about it being from Napa).

Comment: **PS:** This is an *important* lesson. $~$ You may be given more problems where the conditional probabilities are presented in terms of *correctness* or *truthfulness* of some claim, when the actual event of interest is about *what the claimant sais*. $~$  Watch out for these in the future.

Comment: It's all clear now,so easy to get trick with these type of problems.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the denominator, we should have $P(B) * P(I|B)$, since the expert incorrectly predicted the Bordeaux wine was from Napa. So switching 0.9 to 0.1 gives you the desired result.

$$P(N)=\frac{P(N)*P(C|N)}{P(N)*p(C|N)+P(B)*P(I|B)}=  \frac{0.6*0.8}{0.6*0.8+0.4*0.1}=0.92$$

Comment: thank you I see my mistakes now

Answer (score 2):

You should be dividing by $P($wine expert says it is from Napa$)$.

They will say it is from Napa if (i) it is from Napa and they are correct or (ii) it is from Bordeaux and they are incorrect.